# How do I stop onkeypress from looking for keypress when its if statement is no longer met i.e. how do a temporarily deactivate onkeypress (im new)

Tags: python, onkeypress

I did this for all letters and the entire sequence lies in a function. During the first iteration of the variable "letter" it will work fine but during the second iteration, third and so on, the code will run the fix_fall function for past iterations of the variable letter. For instance if the first time letter == "a" fix_fall will only run for when you click "a" but when you change letter to equal "f" it will run fix_fall when you click "a" or "f". How do I get the onkeypress for "a" to stop activating until letter equals "a" again.

```
lenny = 0
def draw_an_letter():
  global letter
  global lenny
  apple_xcor = apple.xcor()
  apple_ycor = apple.ycor()
  drawer_xcor = apple_xcor - 14
  drawer_ycor = apple_ycor - 32
  if lenny > 0:
    del letter
    letter = random.choice(letters)
    letter = letter.lower()
  drawer.goto(drawer_xcor, drawer_ycor)
  drawer.color("white")
  drawer.write(letter, font=("Arial", 35, "bold"))
  lenny = lenny + 1 

def fix_fall():
   fall_apple(apple)
   apple_newxcor = random.randint(-130,150)
   apple.goto(apple_newxcor, 40)
   apple.showturtle()
   draw_an_letter()
   wn.listen()
   if letter == "a":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "a")
   if letter == "b":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "b")
   if letter == "c":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "c")
   if letter == "d":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "d")
   if letter == "e":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "e")
   if letter == "f":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "f")
   if letter == "g":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "g")
   if letter == "h":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "h")
   if letter == "i":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "i")
   if letter == "j":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "j")
   if letter == "k":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "k")
   if letter == "l":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "l")
   if letter == "m":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "m")
   if letter == "n":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "n")
   if letter == "o":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "o")
   if letter == "p":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "p")
   if letter == "q":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "q")
   if letter == "r":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "r")
   if letter == "s":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "s")
   if letter == "t":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "t")
   if letter == "u":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "u")
   if letter == "v":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "v")
   if letter == "w":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "w")
   if letter == "x":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "x")
   if letter == "y":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "y")
   if letter == "z":
      wn.onkeypress(fix_fall, "z")
```

Comment: Can you add more context? How do you call this function? What UI are you using (I'm guessing `turtle`)?

Comment: New info added.

Comment: Ok slightly better but still not enough to help you: 1) what do you want to do with this program? 2) What are `apple`, `letter`, `wn`, and `drawer`? Where do you define them?

Comment: The behaviour you see (`when you change letter to equal "f" it will run fix_fall when you click "a" or "f"`) is caused by the fact that you *register* the callback `fix_fall` when that letter is pressed (I guess, the code is missing), so the next time both `a` and `f` call `fix_fall` when pressed. I think you could register `wn.onkeypress(fix_fall_a, 'a')` and that func will be called when you press `a`, and inside `fix_fall_a` you call `draw_a_letter` (with the correct letter as arg).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this solves the problem, as I did not understand what the problem was (I'll happily edit the answer when you add more info), but meanwhile, I had some fun coding this program: it will write the letter you press in a random x position on the screen (which kinda looks like what you want to do from the snippet you posted).

Notice that I avoided replicating the code 26 times with an unusual construct (for python anyway): a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). What exactly is a closure is beyond the scope of this answer, but you can think of it (in extremely broad terms) as a function bound to a variable.

The function `closure_writer` **creates** a new function, bound to the value `letter` that you have called `closure_writer` with, and **returns** that function.

For each letter, the function `closure_writer` is called, and the *returned* function is linked as callback for that letter.

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase
import turtle


def random_xpos():
    """Move the turtle to a random x position."""
    newxcor = random.randint(-600, 600)
    t.setx(newxcor)


def write_letter(letter):
    """Write a letter in the current spot."""
    t.write(letter, font=("Arial", 35, "bold"))


def closure_writer(letter):
    """Return a function that writes the specified letter."""

    def writer():
        """Write the specified letter."""
        random_xpos()
        write_letter(letter)

    # note that we are NOT calling the function, but returning it
    return writer


# setup the turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
turtle.listen()

# register all the keypress
for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    # closure_writer returns a new function that will be called at each keypress
    # and each function is created with its own letter associated
    turtle.onkeypress(closure_writer(letter), letter)

# start the loop
turtle.mainloop()
```

Cheers!